# Rancher/Kubernetes: New Pods/Deployments not going to newly added node

Tags: rancher, k3s

I am a relative beginner with Rancher and Kubernetes. I have taken over maintenance of a cluster at Brandeis used for students in a robotics lab. The cluster has 4 nodes and around 30 pods. It works great.

I recently successfully added a new node to the cluster, so now it has 4. It seems to be happy and healthy. But when I create a new pod it goes to one of the old nodes (which are far less powerful).

I know there is more info you need to answer this question but there is so much potentially relavant that if you can respond with what info might be helpful I will put it here asap.